# Media Queries not working in IE11 (Resolution problem)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I am using media queries in CSS to scale my web page depending on the screen resolution for both IE11 and Chrome. When I run [this webpage](https://bestfirms.com/what-is-my-screen-resolution/) on chrome (which btw I use to determine my min width) on my 2 different screens I get 1366x768 on my small screen and 1920x1080 on my bigger screen. When I run the same webpage on both screens in IE11 I get 1920x1080 for both. Which means that the media query I am using won't apply on IE since the width is 1920. 
What can I do to fix that problem?

```
.sizing{

 }

@media all and (max-width: 1366px) {
  .sizing{
    zoom: 0.65;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.85);
  }
}
```

Right now it only scales in chrome but not in IE.

Comment: What are you scaling? Is the tool you're using accurate? It doesn't make sense that it would report the same resolution for two different screens. I know that's hard to know but have you tried other tools that do the same thing like [mydevice.io](https://www.mydevice.io/) to see if you get the same results? What specifically are the screens/devices that your checking screen resolution for? _Even if the resolution reports are accurate, it should be an issue. It's the same difference as someone viewing your site on the larger screen._

Comment: Okay I just used the tool you gave me and now it shows a logical resolution of 1366px of width on the smaller screen. However my media query should work on IE according to the previous questions asked on the internet. What do you think could be causing this? Thanks

Comment: You probably need to add a prefix for your CSS property `zoom` for IE11, i.e. `-ms-zoom`. Though, if `zoom` does the same as `transform: scale();`, use that instead without a prefix. Use [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/) to quick search for and check browser compatibility for CSS, JS, and Web APIs. **Note: Currently caniuse.com is a little buggy (not typical) and not displaying some of the exceptions for a given browser.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility) documentation, `-moz-transform` is not supported in IE. You should use `transform` instead. You can try to modify the css like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1366px) {
  .sizing{
    zoom: 0.65;
    transform: scale(0.85);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.85);
  }
}
```